# When is performance improved by using disable/enable keys when adding data to a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, import

Using MySQL 8, I have a number of tables that contain data that is only ever read except they're updated with a delta once a day.  I'm using MyISAM as I understand it's quicker for read-only.  Importing the delta involves adding perhaps 1% of data to the tables, which never replaces any rows and the delta is also distinct.  E.g. If the table contains 11,000,000 rows and I add 20,000 it'll definitely have 11,020,000 when the import is over.  I'm actually programatically adding the rows using large insert statements that add perhaps 2,000 rows at a time.

The question is how to do this most quickly.  Lots of literature would say do this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
# Lots of inserts
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

This does make the inserts faster, but rebuilding the keys on an 11,000,000 row table at the end takes ages.  However, simply:

```
# Lots of inserts
```

on its own is far quicker because we're not rebuilding the entire index, simply adding 'a few' records.

The question is where is the sweet spot where the disable/enable keys trick actually improves performance?  I appreciate there will be a number of factors, such as the number and types of keys, but I wonder if anyone has performed any tests where, perhaps adding more than 10% more rows *generally* favours the disable/enable keys approach?

Answer (score 0):

"MyISAM ... is quicker for read-only" -- That's an old wive's tale.

When changing 1% of a table, there is no advantage (in MyISAM or InnoDB) in disabling keys.  For 50%, then it probably helps.  (No, I don't know where the cutoff is.)

2K rows in a single `INSERT` is about 10 times as fast as 2K 1-line `INSERTs` (in either engine).  (Normally, I recommend inserting somewhere between 100 and 1000 rows at a time; 2K is probably not "too many".)

InnoDB has a "change buffer" which helps it delay *index* changes from insert/update/delete.  This mostly delays the index updates until after the `INSERT` returns to the client as being 'finished'.  In InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, there is no chance of corruption if a crash occurs before it *really* finishes.

Newer versions of MySQL (for InnoDB *only*) can `DROP` and `ADD` an `INDEX` nearly instantly -- leaving the real work to be done in the background.  I am not recommending you try this, since it leaves the table without the index for a brief time.

MyISAM locks the entire table for virtually anything that is done; InnoDB is much more relaxed, due to its 'row locking'.

Even at 10%, I would simply do the `INSERTs` (in batches) in InnoDB.

At any near 100%, I would rebuild a new table then swap it into place (using `RENAME TABLE`).

A tip for the future; Oracle is probably going to remove MyISAM.  It is essentially unusable in any clustering topology.